# How do I calculate values of each objects in two different arrays and push to a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello guys I have two different arrays called `topUp` and `spent` now for a d3 representation I need to take each object index and calculate the percentage difference between the two values.

```
const topUp = Array [
  Object {
    "x": 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    "y": 500,
  },
  Object {
    "x": 2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z,
    "y": 500,
  },
  Object {
    "x": 2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z,
    "y": 500,
  },
]

const spent = Array [
  Object {
    "x": 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    "y": 100,
  },
  Object {
    "x": 2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z,
    "y": 150,
  },
  Object {
    "x": 2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z,
    "y": 320,
  },
]
```

Using this arrays I need to calculate the `spent[i].y * topUp[i].y / 100` and then push the object to a new array like this

```
const difference = Array [
  Object {
    "x": 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    "y": 20,
  },
  Object {
    "x": 2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z,
    "y": 30,
  },
  Object {
    "x": 2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z,
    "y": 64,
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map to calculate `spent[i].y * topUp[i].y / 100`

```
var result = topUp.map((v,i) => {return {x: v.x, y: spent[i].y * v.y / 100 }});
```

This will give u desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple for loop, your formula is wrong though.

```js
const topUp = [{
    "x": '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    "y": 500,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 500,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 500,
  },
];

const spent = [{
    "x": '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    "y": 100,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 150,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 320,
  },
];

const diff = [];

for (let i = 0; i < topUp.length && i < spent.length; i++) {
  const [x, y] = [
    topUp[i].x,
    100 - (topUp[i].y - spent[i].y) / topUp[i].y * 100
  ];
  diff.push({
    x,
    y
  });
}

console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired calculation was a bit different, you can use map function in order to build your desired diff variable.

You can read more about `map` function in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const topUp = [
  {
    "x": '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    "y": 500,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 500,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 500,
  },
]

const spent = [
  {
    "x": '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    "y": 100,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-01-31T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 150,
  },
  {
    "x": '2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z',
    "y": 320,
  },
]

const diff = topUp.map((item, index) => ({ x: item.x, y: 100 - (item.y - spent[index].y) / item.y * 100 }))
console.log(diff)
```